# I can't run Webview javafx

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I'm a beginner who's just starting to write code, but now I'm stuck in trouble. The problem is, I can't run webview.
When I run `Webview webview = new Webview();` what causes this kind of anomaly and how should I fix it?

This is the code I tried to run webview.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Maintest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        WebView web = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = web.getEngine();

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(web);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        arg0.setScene(scene);
        arg0.show();
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: no screenshots of plain text

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)